# How do I release a Pokemon?

Tags: pokemon-go

I have been playing Pokemon Go for a few hours now, and I have caught a couple of different Pokemon. Through my playing, I caught some Pokemon that I do not care for nor want anymore. I looked around around the menu, but I did not see an option to release a Pokemon.

Is there a way to release a Pokemon to clear up your storage?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You do not release them, you can transfer them to the professor, this will award you with 1 candy of the Pokemon type.

You do it by clicking the button with 3 lines on it in the bottom right of the Pokemon stats screen.

[image: Pokemon select screen]

Then clicking on the Transfer button:

[image: options menu for Pokemon]

This can also be done directly from the stat sheet when you capture a Pokemon.

Comment: for all intents and purposes this is basically the same as releasing them

Comment: @Pyritie except.. [we all know what the professor does](https://i.redd.it/w7009jyad9ax.jpg)..